# Mysql how to select and count multi record?

Tags: mysql

I have table like this:

[image]

I want get result like this :

```
a win=2 lose=1 total_bet_result=3
b win=1 lose=1 total_bet_result=2
c win=1 lose=2 total_bet_result=3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT user, 
        SUM(bet_result = 'win') AS win, 
        SUM(bet_result = 'lose') AS lose
        COUNT(*) AS total_bet_result
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY user
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT user,
    SUM(CASE WHEN bet_result = 'win' THEN 1 END) AS 'win',
    SUM(CASE WHEN bet_result = 'lose' THEN 1 END) AS 'lose',
    count(bet_result) as total_bet
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY user
```

Comment: Care to explain it more?

Comment: `CASE` statement is a conditional statement on a column. In above mentioned query, I am putting a condition on `bet_result` and checking if it is equal to `win` returns 1, and using `SUM` function adding up these 1s to have the total count for `win`. Same goes to `lose`. Also because I want these calculations for each user, I group them by `user`. Hope this helps.